# Find kernel of adjoint representation of SU2

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, hermitian-matrices

The task is to find a kernel of representation

$P: SU_2 → \text{Aut}_\mathbb{R}(E), P(A) → X → AXA^{−1}$,
where $E$ is traceless Hermitian matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2+ix_3\\x_2+ix_3&-x_1\end{bmatrix}$$
where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are in $\mathbb{R}$.

As far as I understand, I am supposed to find $A$ such that $AXA^{−1} = X$ for each $X$. How can I proceed with that? Thank you.

Comment: No... you need find $A$ so that $X = AXA^{-1}$ for all $X$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you, I have edited the question

Comment: In this case the matrices are quite small, so you can write down an arbitrary 2x2 matrix for $A$ and compute which equations you get from assuming that $AX=XA$ and $A \in \mathrm{SU}_2$.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova - not that if $\rho: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow End_k(V)$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-module where $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple, it follows $ker(\rho)=(0)$.

Comment: @hm2020 Are you suggesting that if the representation is irreducible, kernel is trivial, right? Since there is a correspondence between irreducible repre. and simple modules.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova - If $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple it has no non-trivial ideals. For any $\mathfrak{g}$-module $\rho$, it follows $ker(\rho) \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$ is an ideal, hence when $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple it follows $ker(\rho)=(0)$ for any such $\rho$.

Comment: Note that the negative identity matrix is in the kernel of the Adjoint repn of $SU(2)$... In $SU(n)$, any scalar matrix will be in the corresponding kernel, so $\omega\cdot 1_n$ with $\omega$ an $n$th root of unity will be in that kernel.

Comment: One of the two $x_2+ix_3$ should have a minus sign.

Comment: Have you tried to just set
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix},\quad
X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2+ix_3\\x_2+ix_3&-x_1\end{bmatrix},
$$
and try to solve for $A$ in $AX=XA$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "Are you suggesting that if the representation is irreducible, kernel is trivial, right? Since there is a correspondence between irreducible repre. and simple modules."

**Answer:**

**Lemma:** If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra and if $\rho$ is any $\mathfrak{g}$-module it follows $ker(\rho) \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$ is an ideal. Hence if $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple (it has no non-trivial ideals) it follows $ker(\rho)=(0)$.

**Proof:**  Let $x\in ker(\rho)$ and let $y \in\mathfrak{g}$. It follows $\rho([y,x])=[\rho(y), \rho(x)]=[\rho(y),0]=0$ hence $[\mathfrak{g},ker(\rho)] \subseteq ker(\rho)$. Hence if $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple it follows $ker(\rho)=(0)$.

The Lie group $SU(n)$ is simple and so is its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask, how do we know, the $g$ is simple here? Is the $g$ the $SU_2$, or $su_2$? Sorry, a bit confused

Comment: @TerezaTizkova - I believe you will find this result proved in a book of Hall on an introduction to the representation theory of Lie groups (in the GTM series). Else it should not be too difficult to calculate the kernel explicitly in low dimensional examples.